# Keyboard type with < > so that user can navigate between multiple text fields

Tags: ios, swift4

[image: Required keyboard type]

I want this type of keyboard for that user can click on > to move to the next text field. What is this type keyboard called? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's textfield's `inputAccessoryView`, it seems to be only available automatically in webview

Comment: You will need to create 2 barButtonItem for < & > and then add them to a toolbar and then set this toolbar as input accessory view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't provided by the framework by default. So you'll either have to build it yourself. By creating a custom UIToolBar with these buttons and attaching it to the keyboard by using notifications as explained [here](https://medium.com/@shenghuawu/observe-ios-keyboard-notifications-a49323813656).

You could also choose to use existing keyboard management libraries to achieve this task with less manual work. One of these libraries is [IQKeyboardManagerSwift](https://cocoapods.org/pods/IQKeyboardManagerSwift)

Comment: Isn't any in-built option for iOS available?

Comment: I mean these are the types of keyboard available for iOS mentioned in this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype . I wanted something of this sort

Comment: @AparajitaSinha it is a keyboard type that is you can set either you can select only number, email, phone etc. you need.. but it is not give you, what's you need..

Comment: Yes so I had to use the library mentioned above. IQKeyboardManagerSwift